# Gia: How to pass event object to handler via eventbus

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am learning how to work with [Gia](https://github.com/giantcz/gia) (for small web projects) and I cannot find out how to pass an event object from one component to an event handler of another component over Gia's eventbus.

Here's two basic components, communicating over the eventbus:

```
class navigation extends Component {
  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
    //
    // Define "Sub-components"
    this.ref = {
      navLinks: [],
    };
  }

  mount() {
    //
    // Listen for clicks on nav.-links
    for (let i = 0; i < this.ref.navLinks.length; i++) {
      const link = this.ref.navLinks[i];
      link.addEventListener("click", this.handleNavLinkClick.bind(this));
    }
  }

  handleNavLinkClick(e) {
    //
    // Emit event
    let clickedLink = e.target;
    if (clickedLink.classList.contains("callHeader")) {
      eventbus.emit("callingSubpageHeader");
    }
  }
}

class subpageHeader extends Component {
  mount() {
    //
    // Listen for call from eventbus
    eventbus.on(
      "callingSubpageHeader",
      this.handleEventBusCall_callHeader.bind(this)
    );
  }
  //
  // Eventbus handler(s)
  handleEventBusCall_callHeader() {
    console.log("The subpage-header was called.");
  }
}
```

The emitting of the event and the subsequent call of the handler inside the second component works just fine. But I would like to pass additional information from the first to the second component when the handler is called. [The Gia documentation mentions that the emit method of the eventbus can pass an eventObject](https://github.com/giantcz/gia#eventbus) to the handler:

> Calls any handlers previously registered with the same event name.
>   Optional event object can be used as a argument, which gets passed
>   into a handlers as an argument.

```
eventbus.emit('eventName'[, eventObject]);
```

Unfortunately, there is no example and I don't know how passing the object works. I tried adding "something" (in this case the link that was clicked in the first component) to the call of the emit-function, but have no idea how/where I can read/use this nor if passing something as an eventObject works this way:

```
class navigation extends Component {
  constructor(element) {
    super(element);
    //
    // Define "Sub-components"
    this.ref = {
      navLinks: [],
    };
  }

  mount() {
    //
    // Listen for clicks on nav.-links
    for (let i = 0; i < this.ref.navLinks.length; i++) {
      const link = this.ref.navLinks[i];
      link.addEventListener("click", this.handleNavLinkClick.bind(this));
    }
  }

  handleNavLinkClick(e) {
    //
    // Emit event
    if (clickedLink.classList.contains("callHeader")) {
      eventbus.emit("callingSubpageHeader", [e.target]);
    }
  }
}
```

It'd be great if someone could explain the concept and syntax of passing an eventObject in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler is passed the object from the event as a parameter, so your handler can grab that object as a variable from its function signature, like this:

```js
handleEventBusCall_callHeader(target) {
  console.log("The subpage-header was called.");
}
```

the variable `target` inside of your event handler is now equal to the object you passed with the event.

When you call the event, you don't need to put your argument in `[]`, that will just put it into an array before passing it which will give you headaches later on. The brackets in the documentation just show that the second argument for `eventbus.emit` is optional.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the explanation, makes perfect sense. I'm still learning and this is great help.